# Cannot get the first element of array whereas map() works as a charm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops, iteration

In a React component want to print out the a value of an object ("name") which is the first element in the array:

```
"production_countries": [
  {
    "iso_3166_1": "US",
    "name": "United States of America"
  }
]
```

This code collapses the app with error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`:

```
<p>
  {
    movie.production_countries &&
    movie.production_countries[0].name
  }
</p>
```

However, if I replace the code above with a `.map()` everything works as a charm.

```
<p>
  {movie.production_countries &&
    movie.production_countries?.map((country, i) => (
      <span key={i}>
        {country.name}
      </span>
    ))}
</p>
```

How can I get the first element of array? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`production_countries` could be an empty array, in which case `[0]` will return undefined, using `?` for early return should work:

```
{
  movie.production_countries &&
  movie.production_countries[0]?.name
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks